# I want to know how to implement this collapse side bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In this figma design I have a collapse sidebar.
Here I have attached my image down below.
But I have no idea how to do this.
When it collapse page should get the full width also direction arrow should comes to other side
Help me with this.
I want to do this using bootstrap.

I have no idea how to do this. I tried searching google but i found nothing

Comment: On SO, we can only help if you will come with code you have tried or else we cant help you.

Comment: And where is your figma design as well as image ? Post at least whatever you have done so far also.